# TypeError Expected: Result, Actual: Future[SimpleResult]

Tags: scala, playframework

I am working on a Scala service in Play to act as a  proxy for another service. The problem I am having is that IntelliJ is giving me a type error saying that I should be returning a `Future[SimpleResult]` instead of a Result Object. Here is what I have:

```
def getProxy(proxyUrl: String) = Action { request =>
  val urlSplit = proxyUrl.split('/')
  urlSplit(0) 
  WS.url(Play.current.configuration.getString("Services.url.um") + proxyUrl).get().map { response =>
    val contentType = response.header("Content-Type").getOrElse("text/json")
    Ok(response.body)
  }
}
```

How do I fix this so I can return a Result object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Play WS.get() returns a `Future[Response]`, which you're mapping to `Future[Result]`, you need to use `Action.async` instead of `Action.apply`:

```
def getProxy(proxyUrl: String) = Action.async { request =>
    val urlSplit = proxyUrl.split('/')
    urlSplit(0) 
    WS.url(Play.current.configuration.getString("Services.url.um") + proxyUrl).get().map { response =>
        val contentType = response.header("Content-Type").getOrElse("text/json")
        Ok(response.body)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep... Had been messing around with Async{} just tried and it worked thanks... Think it's worth leaving the question up?